# Splitting text and getting the count of it

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get the count of characters without spaces.
I tried this code but it counts the spaces .

```
val trimmed = view.String.text.trim()
    if (trimmed.isNotEmpty()){
        val p=trimmed.split("\\s+").toString().length-1
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Kotlin` way:

```
yourString.replace("\\s".toRegex(), "").length
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split string by space

```
val parts = yourString.split(" ")
var count = 0
for (part in parts)
    count += part.length
```

Answer (score 1):

use the method replaceAll() to remove spaces

`String word = yourString. replaceAll(" ", "") ;
int size = word.length() ;`